# Do something with returned Ajax data from multiple SQL queries

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

If I am populating a list with MySQL data using the following:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="first_column"></ul>
<br>
<ul id="second_column"></ul>
```

**JQUERY/AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $.ajax({
    url: "filename.php",
    success: 
    function(data){            
        $("#first_column").html(data);
    }
  })
})
```

**PHP**

```
$conn = OpenCon();

$sql = "SELECT first_column FROM table";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {        
        echo '<li>' .$row['first']. '</li>';
    }
}
```

How can I add a second SQL query (`SELECT second_column FROM table`) to the PHP and output it to `<ul id="second_column"></ul>` from the returned AJAX data? I think I have to use arrays and json, but I am struggling to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your PHP to echo a json encoded string.

```
$conn = OpenCon();

$first_column = '';
$second_column = '';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT first_column FROM table");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  

        //append to `$first_column` instead of echoing directly      
        $first_column .= '<li>' .$row['first']. '</li>';
    }
}

//generate `$second_column` the same way as `$first_column`
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT second_column FROM table");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  

        //append to `$second_column`
        $first_column .= '<li>' .$row['second']. '</li>';
    }
}

//send both `$first_column` and `$second_column` at the same time
echo json_encode(['first_column' => $first_column, 'second_column' => $second_column]);
```

Then, in your ajax, you can select whichever column you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "filename.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#first_column").html(data.first_column);
            $("#second_column").html(data.second_column);
        }
    })
});
```

Alternatively, you could do a separate Ajax call.